# Android : how to post a tweet only by Tweet (not by Direct Message?)

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter

Here is the code I'm using to share a tweet :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.setPackage("com.twitter.android");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My text");
startActivity(intent);
```

This opens a popup enabling the user to share it by Tweet or by Direct Message, when I only want it to be shared by tweet. How can I do that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Probably by using some dedicated Twitter Android API. Moreover, what *you* want does not matter. What the *user* wants matters. [Share where the *user* wants](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/06/28/share-where-the-user-wants.html), rather than artificially restricting them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    Intent tweet = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    tweet.setData(Uri.parse("http://twitter.com/?status=" +   Uri.encode(message)));// replace message by your string message
    startActivity(tweet);
```